# Python if-elif-else not working when in theory it should be?

Tags: python

I am working with python and and for a homework assignment in college, which is now late because of this I cannot get the if-elif-else function to work.. D:

This is my code and I can't get it to work properly. It only prints Nothing to brag about. Even if the score is 1000.

```
score = raw_input("What is your score?")

if (score >= 0, score <= 999):
    print "Nothing to brag about."

elif (score >= 1000, score <= 9999):
    print "Good Score."

elif (score >= 10000):
    print "Very Impressive!"

else:
    print "That's not a legal score!"
```

Comment: You should be parsing the input as a number, using [`int()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#int).

Comment: No, theory says it shouldn't work. Tuples aren't like that.

Answer (score 8):

**First, you don't need those parentheses;**

**Second, you need to use `and` instead of `,`;**

**Third, you need to cast input to `int` because `raw_input` function returns a `string`.**

If you type `help(raw_input)` in interactive terminal, you should see the definition:

```
raw_input(...)
    raw_input([prompt]) -> string
```

Fixed code:

```
score = int(raw_input("What is your score?"))

if score >= 0 and score <= 999:
    print "Nothing to brag about."

elif score >= 1000 and score <= 9999:
    print "Good Score."

elif score >= 10000:
    print "Very Impressive!"

else:
    print "That's not a legal score!"
```

Comment: This leads me back to it only giving me Very Impressive!. I have tried this already to no avail. D:

Comment: @TimothyShaw Thats because the result of raw_input is always a string, so will never be in the ranges you give. You need to cast the input to an integer like I've shown in my answer.

Comment: **Third, `score` as written is a string, not an `int`, so the comparison is invalid.**.  Convert the `score` to an `int` on input.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `and` operator to do your logic properly, or, even better, the syntax for `a<b<c` booleans in Python. Commas usually indicate tuples in Python. Also don't forget to convert your input to an `int`.

```
score = int(raw_input("What is your score?"))

if 0 <= score <= 999:
    print "Nothing to brag about."

elif 1000 <=score <= 9999:
    print "Good Score."

elif score >= 10000:
    print "Very Impressive!"

else:
    print "That's not a legal score!"
```

Comment: Thank you for that! This works now. Sorry I am new to python so thats why I do not know much.

Comment: @TimothyShaw Be aware, that if a user enters a non-number this code will throw an exception. Which will prevent the if-elif-else branch from executing.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you need to cast the result of `raw_input()` to an integer.

Secondly, Python doesn't use brackets around comparators. The structures you had were tuples with boolean values in, which would lead to the unexpected results.

Lastly, Python can chain comparators together to make much more readable code.

```
score = raw_input("What is your score?")

try:
    score = int(score)
except:
    # Casting a non-number to an integer will throw an expection.
    # You need to handle that in some way that makes sense.
    score = -1 # Setting the score to -1 will at least cause the else branch to fire.

if 0 <= score <= 999:
    print "Nothing to brag about."
elif 1000 <= score <= 9999:
    print "Good Score."
elif score >= 10000:
    print "Very Impressive!"
else:
    print "That's not a legal score!"
```

Comment: Thank though Shashank Gupta showed me how it should have been, you provided a great explanation as to why.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
score = raw_input("What is your score?")

if ( int(score) <= 999 and int(score) >= 0):
    print "Nothing to brag about."

elif (int(score) >= 1000 and  int(score) <= 9999):
    print "Good Score."

elif (int(score) >= 10000):
    print "Very Impressive!"

else:
    print "That's not a legal score!"
```